# Reducing time complexity of sieve Method for finding primes

Tags: c#-4.0

Please consider the following code

```
public void printSievePrimes()
        {
            int[] temp = new int[count];
            for (int j = 2; j * j < temp.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int i = j * j; i < temp.Length; i += j)
                {
                    primesFound[i] = false;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < temp.Length; i++)
            {
                if (primesFound[i] != false)
                    Console.WriteLine("PrimeFound is:" + i);
            }

        }
```

The above method is called sieve method of finding primes.It goes like this;

1 start from 2 and cancel out it subsequent facotors like 4,6,8...

2 start from 3 and cancel out it subsequent facotors like 9,12,15...

3 4..is already cancelled out

4 start from 5 ...so on

I have done it and it is working well.but want to reduce
        it's complexity to O(n) or O(nlogn) What could be done?
Another problem is that i have to loop through array to get the largest prime is there way to find the largest prime so found using efficient way?

Comment: just calculate Sum [j = 2 .. Sqrt(j)] (( N - j^2) / j)

Comment: its order is O(nloglogn) in literature

Comment: Here is what walfram says : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28N+-+j%5E2%29%2Fj%29+from+j+%3D+2+to+sqrt%28N%29

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you posted has complexity O(N log(N)).  You can speed things up a little though with this change... I do not know if it will improve the complexity of the algorithm (probably will)

```
for (int j = 2; j * j < temp.Length; j++)
{
   if (primesFound[j] == false) continue;

   for (int i = j * j; i < temp.Length; i += j)
   {
      primesFound[i] = false;
   }
}
```

Basically... the code you posted will not skip the number 4 because it never checks to see if the number has been already cancelled out.